# I'm with problems in steps 4 and 5, the tutorial Overlays

Tags: ros, rosws, overlay, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In steps 4 and 5, I can not execute the commands of their.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays

The following erros are shown:

```
iohan@iohan-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-SFF-PC:~$ roslocate info turtlebot | rosws merge -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosws", line 64, in <module>
    sys.exit(rosinstall.rosws_cli.rosws_main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/rosws_cli.py", line 551, in rosws_main
    return ws_commands[command](workspace, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/rosws_cli.py", line 259, in cmd_merge
    config=config)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/multiproject_cli.py", line 612, in prompt_merge
    extra_verbose))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/multiproject_cli.py", line 512, in _get_element_diff
    diff = string_diff(old_val, new_val)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/common.py", line 139, in string_diff
    str1 = str1.ljust(len(str2))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ljust'
```

the previous steps were executed successfully.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42788/i%27m-with-problems-in-steps-4-and-5,-the-tutorial-overlays./) by [Iohan Goncalves](https://answers.ros.org/users/3113/iohan-goncalves/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-01**:
What does `rosws info` show?

**Comment by [Iohan Goncalves](https://answers.ros.org/users/3113/iohan-goncalves/) on 2012-09-01**:
iohan@iohan-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-SFF-PC:~$ rosws info
workspace: /home/iohan/fuerte_workspace
ROS_ROOT: /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

Localname                 S SCM  Version-Spec UID  (Spec)  URI  (Spec) [http(s)://...]

---

**Comment by [Iohan Goncalves](https://answers.ros.org/users/3113/iohan-goncalves/) on 2012-09-01**:
turtlebot   hg   e47d5a1dca1c kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot
sandbox
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
/opt/ros/fuerte/share
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a known bug:

https://kforge.ros.org/vcstools/trac/ticket/65

Will be fixed after next release, until then, do the merge manually, just call
roslocate info turtlebot
and add the resulting test at the bottom of your .rosinstall file.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0